# Istio 1.6.5 gateway timeout errors

Tags: istio

Intermittently we are seeing 504 gateway time out (504) errors when accessing application from browser. We upgraded istio from 1.4.3 to 1.6.5. There was no issue with 1.4.3.

Comment: How did you upgrade it? As there were a lot of changes since 1.4.3 and 1.6.5 you can´t just upgrade it, as it´s not going to work. How did you install your 1.4.3 version, with istioctl or helm?

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to upgrade istio from 1.4.x to 1.6.x you should first upgrade from 1.4.x to 1.5.x, then upgrade from 1.5.x to 1.6.x

I have followed a theme on [istio discuss](https://discuss.istio.io/t/upgrading-istio-1-4-3-to-1-6-0/6814/16) about upgrade created by@laurentiuspurba.

I have changed it a little for your use case, so an upgrade from 1.4.3 to 1.5.0, then from 1.5.0 to 1.6.8

Take a look at below steps, before using that on your environment I would suggest to test that on some test environment.

---

1.Follow istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#download) and install istioctl 1.4.3 and 1.5 with:

```
curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.4.3 sh -
curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.5.0 sh -
curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.6.8 sh -
```

2.Add the istioctl 1.4.3 to your path

```
cd istio-1.4.3
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
```

3.Install istio 1.4.3

```
istioctl manifest generate > $HOME/generated-manifest.yaml
kubectl create namespace istio-system
kubectl apply -f generated-manifest.yaml
```

4.Check if everything works correct.

```
kubectl get pod -n istio-system
kubectl get svc -n istio-system
istioctl version
```

5.Add the istioctl 1.5 to your path

```
cd istio-1.5.0
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
```

6.Install [istio operator](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2019/introducing-istio-operator/) for future upgrade.

```
istioctl operator init
```

7.Prepare IstioOperator.yaml

```
nano IstioOperator.yaml
```

---

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: default
  tag: 1.5.0
```

8.Before the upgrade use below commands

```
kubectl -n istio-system delete service/istio-galley deployment.apps/istio-galley
kubectl delete validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/istio-galley
```

9.Upgrade from 1.4.3 to 1.5 with istioctl upgrade and prepared IstioOperator.yaml

```
istioctl upgrade -f IstioOperator.yaml
```

10.After the upgrade use below commands

```
kubectl -n istio-system delete deployment istio-citadel istio-galley istio-pilot istio-policy istio-sidecar-injector istio-telemetry
kubectl -n istio-system delete service istio-citadel istio-policy istio-sidecar-injector istio-telemetry
kubectl -n istio-system delete horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/istio-pilot horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/istio-telemetry
kubectl -n istio-system delete pdb istio-citadel istio-galley istio-pilot istio-policy istio-sidecar-injector istio-telemetry
kubectl -n istio-system delete deployment istiocoredns
kubectl -n istio-system delete service istiocoredns
```

11.Check if everything works correct.

```
kubectl get pod -n istio-system
kubectl get svc -n istio-system
istioctl version
```

12.I have deployed a bookinfo app to check if everything work correct.

```
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml
kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml
```

13.Results

```
curl -v xx.xx.xxx.xxx/productpage | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK


istioctl version
client version: 1.5.0
control plane version: 1.5.0
data plane version: 1.5.0 (8 proxies)
```

14.Add the istioctl 1.6.8 to your path

```
cd istio-1.6.8
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
```

15.Prepare IstioOperator.yaml

```
nano IstioOperator.yaml
```

---

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: default
  tag: 1.6.8
```

16.Upgrade from 1.5.0 to 1.6.8 with istioctl upgrade and prepared IstioOperator.yaml

```
istioctl upgrade -f IstioOperator.yaml
```

17.To upgrade the Istio data plane, you will need to re-inject it.

If you’re using automatic sidecar injection, you can upgrade the sidecar by doing a rolling update for all the pods:

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment --namespace <namespace with auto injection>
```

If you’re using manual injection, you can upgrade the sidecar by executing:

```
kubectl apply -f < (istioctl kube-inject -f <original application deployment yaml>)
```

18.Results

```
curl -v xx.xx.xxx.xxx/productpage | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK


istioctl version
client version: 1.6.8
control plane version: 1.6.8
data plane version: 1.6.8 (8 proxies)
```

---

Hope you find this useful. If you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

default timeout = 15 sec.

you can set an explicit timeout in the [Virtual Service](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRoute)